# Give dynamic value to a Form variable in Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Im creating an app in Oracle Apex and I having a problem. I have a report that showns every order made. I can enter new orders by pressing "add order". This is the screen that appears when I press it:
[image]

I want that when the user selects the product, it price per unit (stored in the database "products") appears in "Product Price per Unit". Then, when the user selects also the total items, the total price can be calculated as Total Items * Product Price.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first select product. Create "Set value" dynamic action on it so that it populates the `price per unit` item.

Create yet another dynamic "Set value" action on the `total items` item which would calculate `price * total items` and put the result into `total price`.

In order for dynamic action to work, don't forget to

- set **items to submit** to item(s) used in query (`P12_PRODUCT` in your  case)
- set affected elements to item which will be affected by that dynamic action (`price per unit` in one case, `total price` in another)

Comment: I have done that already. I have a dynamic action that do his: When products change, then it will set the value for product price per unit like this: SELECT PRICE
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = :P12_PRODUCT  considering that when product is selected, that variable returns the product ID. However, nothing is displayed. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: It's because P12_PRODUCT's value isn't in session state. In order to do it, it has to be *submitted*. I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: So, how can I submitted it without exiting this wizard? Sorry if I look a little noob on this.

Comment: As I said: put P12_PRODUCT into "items to submit" property in dynamic action.

Comment: It works! I didn´t see at first "items to submit". Thank you so much for your help!